# PHP code with two conditions stopped working

Tags: php

I am attaching the code below, which worked correctly in the morning and is now not running.

I did not make any changes, a few hours ago everything worked. I don't believe it's caching (I use Cloudflare) because PHP runs on the server, not the client.

What could be the problem? If there was an error in the code, it would simply not work, but it stopped working just a few hours ago, while the rest of the time it worked perfectly.

```
$geoplugin = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
if ( is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude']) && is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude']) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $lat = $geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude'];
    $long = $geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude'];
    if ($geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode'] == 'US') {
        echo do_shortcode ('[sc name="web_code"][/sc]');
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: @aynber I don't see the shortcode content, there's a couple of buttons and a text

Comment: @aynber the page source also shows empty content

Comment: You'll need to do some troubleshooting, then. Use the Wordpress logger to log the response you're getting from geoplugin, if any. I would recommend using cURL instead of file_get_contents, as cURL is a bit more robust.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for your fruitful advice. Unfortunately, I'm not very good at using cURL. Could you please give some advice on how to implement this correctly?